# How to change tmux `status line` directory at startup?

Tags: tmux

I notice when running tmux, it always starts at `/home/user/` directory regardless of the current working directory of shell where tmux started.

I confirmed this by running `pwd` at statusline:

```
set -g status-right "#(pwd)"
```

I want to run some shell scripts at the statusline but I don't want to manually handle the changing-directory stuff for all my scripts.

What I want is for tmux to change directory to where it started/invoked.

How can I do just that?

Comment: Are you calling tmux inside the script? Probably not the ideal way to handle sub-processes...

Comment: @0xSheepdog nope, I'm calling a script inside tmux statusline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon submitting an [issue](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1488) at tmux repo, It turns out that they already have it fixed but it's still in the `release-candidate` stage. so I had to rebuid from source.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ ps -ef | grep tmux
username 13965 12977  0 13:03 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto tmux

$ cd /tmp

/tmp $ tmux

(within tmux) /tmp $ ps -ef | grep tmux
username 14244 12977  0 13:04 pts/2    00:00:00 tmux
username 14246     1  0 13:04 ?        00:00:00 tmux
username 14269 14247  0 13:04 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto tmux

(within tmux) /tmp $ ls -l /proc/14244/cwd /proc/14246/cwd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 username  username  0 Sep 25 13:07 /proc/14244/cwd -> /tmp/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 username  username  0 Sep 25 13:07 /proc/14246/cwd -> /tmp/
```

It looks like the working directory of both the tmux client and server processes *is* the directory tmux was started in, *but* any processes started from tmux status line, like the `#(pwd)` in your `status-right` line, are run with `$HOME` as their working directory.

Changing this behavior would require modifying the `tmux` source code and compiling your own version of it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try sending feature request to tmux devs and hope it will be implemented. I guess I still have to handle this manually.

Comment: [Here is the line that runs the "jobs", including the shell commands included in status strings.](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/83b2d5c5132f3c8cec8a7732fed8fd58f30e8554/format.c#L300) The third parameter could be a directory, but it just specifies NULL, and so it causes the job to be executed in home directory if possible, and in `/` if not. In other places where `job_run()` is used with the directory specified, it is specified with `server_client_get_cwd(item->client, s)`.